# How to listen to a FocusNode with GetX in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I've just discovered [GetX](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx) and I love it! Is there a neat way of listening to a FocusNode with GetX instead of using a StatefulWidget?

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomTextFieldState createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomContainer(
      isFocused: _focusNode.hasFocus,
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a `StatelessWidget` or a `GetView<MyController>` and add the focus node in the controller

```
class MyController extends GetXController {
   final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
   
   @override
   void onInit() {
        focusNode.addListener((){ ...do some stuff }));
        super.onInit();
   }

   @override
   onClose() {
     focusNode.dispose();
     super.onClose();
   }
}
```

Then you can use this in your widget

```
...     
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomContainer(
      isFocused: controller.focusNode.hasFocus,
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: controller.focusNode.focusNode,
      ),
    );
  }
```